# Fourier transform of $f\circ A$ where $A$ linear and $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$

Tags: linear-transformations, partial-derivative, fourier-transform

Let $A: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be a linear map and $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$. I would like to express the fourier transform of $f_A:= f\circ A$ in terms of the Fourier transform $\hat{f}$ of $f$.

Also for which $A$ do we have $\hat{f_A} = \hat{f} \circ A$, other than for $A=id$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you should require that $A$ is invertible. Because if $f\in L^1$ (or $L^2$) and $A$ is not invertible,  there is no guarantee that $f\circ A\in L^1$ (or $L^2$): trivially, if $A=0$ and $f(0)\neq 0$, then 
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}|f\circ A|^p(x)dx=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}|f(0)|^pdx=\infty,\quad \forall p\in [1,\infty) $$
If $A$ is invertible, then by a change of variables
\begin{align*}\widehat{f\circ A}(\xi)&=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f(Ax)e^{-ix\xi}dx=|\det A^{-1}|\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f(x)e^{-iA^{-1}x\cdot \xi}dx=\\ 
&=|\det A^{-1}|\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f(x)e^{-ix\cdot (A^{-1})^*\xi}dx=|\det A^{-1}|\hat{f}\left((A^{-1})^*\xi\right) \end{align*}
Where $A^*$ is the transpose of $A$. Thus 
$$\widehat{f\circ A}=\hat{f}\circ A \iff A=(A^{-1})^* $$
and the latter condition is satisfied iff the matrix $A$ is orthogonal.

Comment: I would suggest using \begin{align} here instead of a run on equation.

Comment: Right. Of course $A$ is _real_, so $A^*$ is just the transpose, and one should probably say "orthogonal" instead of "unitary"..

Comment: Right, thanks, and also the conjugate transpose is just the transpose.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not given that $A$ is invertible the function $f_A$ need not *have* a Fourier transform in the classical sense. For example if $A=0$ then $f_A=f(0)$, and non-zero constants don't have Fourier transforms.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $(A^T)^{-1}$?

Comment: By the way, there is no assumption that $A$ is invertible.

Comment: @JuliánAguirre Eewps. Was actually mis-recalling the argument for _orthogonal_ matrices...